Angular SSR conversion : Unhandled Promise rejection: NotYetImplemented
In an Angular client-side rendered application conversion into sever side rendering (SSR), I am facing the issue below after serving the local Angular setup project:
Unhandled Promise rejection: NotYetImplemented ; Zone: \<root\> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: NotYetImplemented

It may be coming from the Amplify AWS Auth library. For the user login system, we are using AWS's Auth service.
Can anyone please help me on this issue?

Are you trying to interact with DOM elements on server side? This is not recommended, you should do this on client side instead. See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/57182
